# Http URL Connection unable to handle redirects

Tags: java, android, network-programming, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to open a connection with the help of `HttpURLConnection` class.

I've tried this code to handle a URL, but on seeing Logs, I find that it's unable to get the redirected URLs. In the sample code, you will see that to get the URL, I'm using a `while` Loop, and due to this it's logging the same URL. I'm eagerly looking for a better fix for the problem. I hope the problem is clear.

Here is the sample code that I'm using :-

```
 Log.d(TAG,"URL received : --- >"+downloadURL);
            URL url=new URL(downloadURL);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            Log.d(TAG,httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage()+" Append with "+httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
            while(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM)
            {
                httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                URL url1=httpURLConnection.getURL();
            Log.d(TAG,"Redirected URL = "+url1);
            }

             InputStream inptStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

Here is the output of logcat :-

```
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.814 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.815 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.815 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.815 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
03-08 13:28:38.815 22597-23668/abhirojpanwar.tablayout D/AsyncImageDownloader: Redirected URL = https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `HttpURLConnection` class, there is a `static` method called `setFollowRedirects`, here's what it's javadoc says:

> Sets whether HTTP redirects (requests with response code 3xx) should
>   be automatically followed by this class. True by default. Applets
>   cannot change this variable.  If there is a security manager, this
>   method first calls the security manager's checkSetFactory method to
>   ensure the operation is allowed. This could result in a
>   SecurityException.

By default it's always `true` and hence, you will get 200 response with redirected URL. If you don't want that to happen then you need to set `setFollowRedirects` to false. Below snippet demonstrates this:

```
URL url=new URL("https://unsplash.com/photos/65sru5g6xHk/download");
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpURLConnection.connect();
System.out.println(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP){
   URL redirectUrl = new URL(httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location"));
   System.out.println(redirectUrl);
}
InputStream inptStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

Output:

```
302
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488869154849-3547ed9ed8dd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=100&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=b688408cbd18238a8fd1b6355e8d563d
```

Also, it returns 302 and not 301. So you need to use `HTTP_MOVED_TEMP` constant for comparison.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have understood it but what exactly is getting 200 responses with redirected URL?

Comment: By default, `setFollowRedirects` is true, that means it will automatically redirect to the new URL and return the response received from it (which is 200).

Comment: so setting it to false, I set it to not check for URL redirects, which I will be later doing my self in the loop, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what you need to do

Comment: After applying the fix, infinite loop has stopped, but it is still showing the redirected URL same as URL it received before running the check. Any insights about where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Redirect URL will be in `location` header. I have updated my answer to extract the redirect url from location header (in `if`), could you please have a look.

Comment: It is still posting the same solution, I might be going wrong somewhere. can you please post the output of your screen? @DarshanMehta

Comment: I have added the output. Have you tried with my updated code in the answer (the one that extracts location header)?

Comment: Yeah, I was missing the setFollowRedirects(False). I might have overlooked it when I removed the code. Thanx :)

Comment: I'm probably late to this. But for some reason in my Java application, this code does not work. If i open via a browser through the application it redirects, but if I do this, the redirect never happens. Been banging my head for a little bit.

I'm implementing a docusign API and it requires an Authorization code first to use the API. You get an Auth code from a redirected url you get from making a request.